# Multiple RUN instructions vs. single CMD to execute setup script in Dockerfile to initialize container

Tags: docker

What the is best practice for using many RUN commands in a Dockerfile to setup the image vs. a single CMD instruction to execute a script when the container starts?

For example:

```
FROM  centos:latest

RUN useradd myuser
RUN mkdir -p /usr/local/myapp
ADD ./resources/myapp.zip /usr/local/myapp
RUN unzip /usr/local/myapp/myapp.zip
RUN chown -R myuser:myuser /usr/local/myapp

CMD ["/usr/local/myapp/bin/app"]
```

vs.

```
FROM  centos:latest

ADD ./resources/myapp.zip /
ADD ./resources/setup.sh / 
RUN chmod +x /setup.sh

# setup.sh will create the user, extract the zip, execute the binary
CMD ["/setup.sh"]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first example will be better for running `app` multiple times. If you were to use `ENTRYPOINT` instead of `CMD` then you could make the container behave as if it was `app` (because it would run `app` with anything you passed in on the commandline as arguments). If you later wanted to use this image as a base for another image, you could still access `app`.

The second example will run a bit slower since it must extract the zip file each time you `docker run` and you cannot use `app` easily if you make this a parent image, since `app` hasn't been installed.

In general I would suggest using the first format, but the second one is fine for trivial zips and throwaway images and containers.

Comment: Thank you!  I hadn't considered the fact that setup.sh would be run everytime you start a container from the image.  In my case - it would be better for `app` to be part of the image rather than extracted every time.

Comment: @Owen That's the purpose of `CMD`:
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd